# OpenShift 3.5 Architecture - VM Provisioning

Tags: openshift

I have been tasked with recommending the VM provisioning for an OpenShift production environment.  The OpenShift installation documents don't really detail a lot of different options.  I know that we want High Availability (which means multiple masters) but some of the things that I'm a bit confused by are:

- separate hosts for etcd
- infrastructure nodes

Do I need separate hosts/nodes for etcd?  (advantages seem to be performance related but would like to better understand)

Do I need separate hosts/nodes for the infrastructure components (registry, router, etc.) or can these just be hosted on the master nodes?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK etcd can be on same host as master unless you really have a big cluster and want maintenance of etcd separate of openshift cluster.

Running routers on dedicated nodes help having high availability and reduce chances of nodes running into health issues due to other container work loads running on same machine.  applications inside openshift cluster can run even if all masters go down (may be rare)   but router nodes need to be available all the time for serving traffic.

There are many reference architectures published by redhat  checkout blog.openshift.com and also redhat.com official docs

Answer (score 0):

etcd and masters can be installed in the same node or separately. Here you can find some [best practices for etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd-operator/blob/master/doc/best_practices.md). As you see, here is recommended that it is installed separately and this is what I would suggest if you can "afford" more servers. If not, co-locating masters and etcds we can say is symbiotic in that masters are CPU intensive whereas etcd uses a lot of disk IO and memory.

Regarding infrastructure deployments such as routers, docker-registry, EFK stack, metrics and so forth, the recommended deployment configuration (all within your possibilities) is that masters are not schedulable, and they worry only about serving the API and controlling the nodes. Then you can split your schedulable nodes into infrastructure and compute nodes.

- Infrastructure nodes will only host applications used by the cluster itself or by other applications (i.e. Gitlab or Nexus)
- Worker/Compute nodes will host business applications

Having a multi-master installation with HA routers is of course the best solution, but then you have to decide how you want to provide this HA, is it with an external LoadBalancer or with IP Failover?

As @debianmaster mentioned, there are several reference architecture documents you can read. [Like this one here](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-container-platform-reference-architecture-implementation-guides/)